Adding vertical space between html elements (divs) within the same container
(Edit: as after applying the below solution I'm now able to have spaces between feed blocks on desktop view but it didn't worked on mobile view)
I have the following code and it works well by shuffling the elements within the container but the problem is that the content blocks show up close to each other with no vertical space between them.
I tried to add many tags like p and br between them to get the desired space but it caused a non arranged space so some blocks got the space and some not and sometimes it stops the shuffling at all.
So I need some way to add space between all div elements while keeping the shuffling function on.


  // Function to shuffle the order of elements within a container
  function shuffleElements(container) {
    var elements = container.children;
    for (var i = elements.length; i >= 0; i--) {
      container.appendChild(elements[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    
    }
  }

  // Wait for the page to fully load before shuffling the elements
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('your-container-id'); // Replace 'your-container-id' with the ID of the container div that holds the RSS feed divs
    shuffleElements(container);

  });
<div id="your-container-id">

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/saudioffers6" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="500" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/saudioffers6" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/saudioffers6">‏عروض السعودية  saudi offers‏</a></blockquote>
</div>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/diyprocom" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="500" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/diyprocom" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/diyprocom">‏‎Diy pro‎‏</a></blockquote></div>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MarinaFish2019" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="500" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/MarinaFish2019" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MarinaFish2019">‏مارينا للأسماك والرخويات‏</a></blockquote></div>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/nursery.libya" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="500" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/nursery.libya" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/nursery.libya">‏مشتل تمنهنت‏</a></blockquote></div>
</div>




here is my code:

It's going to be largely difficult to help debug without seeing your code. You can try making a code pen if it wont post here, but it's likely that the reason it wont post here is because your example is not a MRE. You want to recreate your issue from the ground up with only the parts absolutely needed to recreate the issue.

I agree with @asyncawait that it's difficult to debug without seeing your code. Have you tried CSS margins or padding? Maybe using a grid and gap?

I have so very low knowledge about the whole issue and to be honest I got the code with some help but couldn't find the helper any more and the spacing issue is killing all the success we got

@asyncawait
I finally added the code, please check it

@mykaf
I finally added the code, please check it

Your stack snippet is causing an error.

When I run on jsfiddle, these appear to line up vertically; do you have some CSS that would lay these out horizontally, such that they could have vertical space between?

the given solution by David Garcia does make space between blocks on desktop but not on mobile, is there anything I can do to let it appears on mobile, I'm using shopify by the way

You can add some styles to add vertical space between elements.
Basically you may want to add some padding or margin at the bottom of each children of #your-container-id except to the last one.
To achieve this you can try the following code:
<style>
    #your-container-id > *:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 50px; /* change this with the value you want */
    }
</style>


Thank you very much it worked as requested and the shuffling still operating

I'm glad to hear that

Hello David, I'm sorry but the solution worked on desktop but not working on cellphone view, is there anything we can do?

I've been able to solve the mobile view issue by using the below code, and it works for both desktop and mobile.
Thank you all


<style> 
        #your-container-id { 
          
           /* Using the grid property */ 
            display: grid; 
  
            /* Making equal spaced divs */ 
            gap: 1rem; 
            
        }
</style>



